# PHP not creating database

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Struggling now for a day. Need to make a database in PHP (if not existing) and after make sure it is empty (if already was existing). But somehow I probably miss something essential and nothing happens. Looks like it just skips the creation and the delete part altogether.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

//Database variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Somename";
$password = "Verysecret";
$dbname = "TESTDB";
$temptable = "tablename";

//Open database
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully to database: ",$dbname,"<br>" ;
?><br><?php

//Create table if not existing yet (syntax error here?)
echo "Creating table if non existing","<br>";
$conn->select_db('$dbname');
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NON EXIST `{$temptable}` (
`xml_date` datetime,
`xml_duration` int(2),
`xml_boat` VARCHAR(30),
`xml_itinerary` VARCHAR(30),
`xml_dep_arr` VARCHAR(30),
`xml_spaces` INT(2),
`xml_rate_eur` decimal(4,2),
`xml_rate_gbp` decimal(4,2),
`xml_rate_usd` decimal(4,2))";

//This part not showing up in output at all! 
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){  
     echo "Table created successfully";  
     } else {  
        echo "Table is not created successfully ";  
     }  

//Deleting rows if table existed already (same syntax error here?)
echo "Making sure table is empty","<br>";
$sql = "DELETE * FROM `{$temptable}`";

 mysqli_close($conn); 

?>
```

All I see when I run (Localy with Mamp)is:

> Connected successfully to
>   database: TESTDB
>
> Creating table if non existing Making sure table is empty

The Database is not created, when I create it myself in SequelPro before and add some rows.

Help, searching now a day! What am I doing wrong? Lost in quotes, back quotes, double quotes? Overseeing the obvious?

Comment: `DELETE *` that's invalid plus you didn't execute it yet.

Comment: echo $sql and run it against in db, you may get detailed error

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NON EXIST` isn't proper syntax. Consult https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Comment: Your code failed on too many levels. Please go through the official documentations.

Answer (score 1):

Let's iterate over what you used here.

`DELETE *`, is invalid since the asterisk is used for [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) and not `DELETE`.

The basic syntax is `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE col_x = ?` (with optional `WHERE` clause).

Example:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Your table creation syntax is incorrect, the basic syntax is:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
```

as per the documentation.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

which uses the keywords `IF NOT EXISTS` and not your `IF NON EXIST`.

You also didn't execute the `DELETE` query.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

and check for errors on it also:

- http://php.net/mysqli_error

Plus, as Chris was so nice to point out in comments; variables don't get parsed in single quotes.

Either remove them from `$conn->select_db('$dbname');` as in either

- `$conn->select_db($dbname);`

or set in double quotes:

- `$conn->select_db("$dbname");`

Edit:

If the goal here is to get rid of the table entirely (after and seeing your DELETE query), then both `DELETE` and `TRUNCATE` are not what you want to use here, but `DROP TABLE`.

Consult the documentation:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html

Basic example:

```
DROP [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF EXISTS]
    tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...
    [RESTRICT | CASCADE]
```

Comment: @chris85 Thanks Chris, please keep your comment intact here, I've made an edit to the answer and quoting what you said; that eluded me for some reason. Edit: Oh, you deleted your comment I was responding to. I'll just keep these "for the record" ;-)

Comment: Thanks Fred, my excuse for the mistakes is the short time (two weeks) I try to wrap my head around PHP. I guess I hoped to find answers on this site but am now aware that some copy paste solution only gravitated the issues. Need urgently to find some good documentation of up to date code ONLY so the cloud in my head materialises to knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Try this , i got the table created

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

//Database variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "detecttn_user";
$password = "Azer12345";
$dbname = "detecttn_teststack";
$temptable = "test ";

//Open database
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully to database: $dbname <br>" ;
?><br><?php

//Create table if not existing yet (syntax error here?)
echo "Creating table if non existing","<br>";

   $sql ="SHOW TABLES LIKE '$temptable'";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){  
     echo "Table exist";  
     } else {  
        echo "Table does not exist";  
        // if table not exist create it
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $temptable (
`xml_date` datetime,
`xml_duration` int(2),
`xml_boat` VARCHAR(30),
`xml_itinerary` VARCHAR(30),
`xml_dep_arr` VARCHAR(30),
`xml_spaces` INT(2),
`xml_rate_eur` decimal(4,2),
`xml_rate_gbp` decimal(4,2),
`xml_rate_usd` decimal(4,2))";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$sql ="SHOW TABLES LIKE '$temptable'";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){  
     echo "Table created";  
     } else {  
        echo "Table creation failed";  
     }  
     }  

//Deleting rows if table existed already (same syntax error here?)
echo "Making sure table is empty","<br>";
$sql2 = "TRUNCATE TABLE $temptable";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)){  
     echo "Table is empty";  
     } else {  
        echo "Error";  
     }  
 mysqli_close($conn); 

?>
```

Comment: Yes the sql variable is not executed. But please notify the OP.

Comment: Corrected code most helpful. Understand my mistakes . . . all of them. Focussed too much on similar solutions instead of proper documentation. Any suggestions about some good online documentation. Get very confused from discussions still mentioning outdated syntaxes. Not really relevant to newbe like me.

Comment: One more thing, noticed that upon implementing your code. The line "Table created successfully" is displayed, even when the table already existed. Probably related to the working of the exec comand. How to apply a message only when created and when not e.g.  "Table already exist"

Comment: @John "CREATE" command in MySQL is not return value command so that it always return false(not like SELECT). To check if the command "CREATE" success or not, you can use "SHOW TABLES" to check after executing the "CREATE" command.